# Erro ao desserializar dados JSON da Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, desserialização

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SoftluxWebCore.Models.Tabelas.Financeiro.CaixasModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

Quando vou tentar desserializar um dado de json me da esse erro acima

```
        CaixasModel Caixas;
        CaixasViewModel CaixasVM = new CaixasViewModel();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Caixas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaixasModel>(resul);
                CaixasVM.Bcx_codigo = Caixas.Bcx_codigo;
                CaixasVM.Bcx_Nome = Caixas.Bcx_Nome;
                CaixasVM.Cba_Saldo_inicial = Caixas.Cba_Saldo_inicial;
                CaixasVM.Cba_PDV = Caixas.Cba_PDV.Equals(true) ? true : false;
                CaixasVM.Bcx_situacao = Caixas.Bcx_situacao.Equals("A") ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return View(CaixasVM);
```

Acima está meu código, estou desserializando em uma model, então não consigo utilizar `<List>`
Eu utilizo uma WebApi que converte o objeto em json e envia pro meu projeto, vou inserir o método mais a baixo.
JSON Recebido:

> [{"Bcx_codigo":1,"Bcx_Nome":"PRINCIPAL","Cba_Saldo_inicial":2000.0,"Bcx_tipo":"C","Cba_PDV":false,"Bcx_situacao":"A","Emp_codigo":1},{"Bcx_codigo":24,"Bcx_Nome":"SECUNDARIO","Cba_Saldo_inicial":null,"Bcx_tipo":"C","Cba_PDV":null,"Bcx_situacao":"A","Emp_codigo":1},{"Bcx_codigo":25,"Bcx_Nome":"asdas","Cba_Saldo_inicial":2312.0,"Bcx_tipo":"C","Cba_PDV":true,"Bcx_situacao":"A","Emp_codigo":1}]

**CaixasModel**

```
namespace SoftluxWebCore.Models.Tabelas.Financeiro
{
public class CaixasModel
{
    public int? Bcx_codigo { get; set; }
    public string Bcx_Nome { get; set; }
    public string Bcx_tipo { get; set; }
    public float? Cba_Saldo_inicial { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> usr_cod_criacao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> usr_dt_hr_criacao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> usr_cod_alteracao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> usr_dt_hr_alteracao { get; set; }
    public string Bcx_situacao { get; set; }
    public bool? Cba_PDV { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emp_codigo { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Método na WebAPI**

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("findAll")]
    public HttpResponseMessage findAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var caixas = (from bc in bdprincipalEntities.Bancos_Caixas
                          join c in bdprincipalEntities.Contas_Bancarias on bc.Bcx_codigo
                          equals c.Bcx_codigo into c_c
                          from c in c_c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new
                          {
                              Bcx_codigo = bc.Bcx_codigo,
                              Bcx_Nome = bc.Bcx_Nome,
                              Cba_Saldo_inicial = c.Cba_Saldo_inicial,
                              Bcx_tipo = bc.Bcx_tipo,
                              Cba_PDV = c.Cba_PDV,
                              Bcx_situacao = bc.Bcx_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO",
                              Emp_codigo = bc.Emp_codigo
                          }).Where(x => x.Bcx_tipo.Equals(TipoBanco)).ToList();

            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(caixas));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: var caixas é uma lista... não deveria ser do tipo CaixasModel?
Seu ToList() no final que parece ser seu problema... no trecho .Where(x => x.Bcx_tipo.Equals(TipoBanco)).ToList(); sempre deve retornar apenas um resultado?

Comment: Não sabia como definir o tipo como CaixasModel na WebApi, mas sua respota a baixo solucionou, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está tentando desserializar uma **Lista** sendo que espera na verdade um objeto **CaixasModel**.

Se atente nessa trecho da exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'SoftluxWebCore.Models.Tabelas.Financeiro.CaixasModel'

Resumindo diz exatamente oque coloquei no primeiro paragrafo.

Reveja esse trecho do seu código:

```
var caixas = (from bc in bdprincipalEntities.Bancos_Caixas
                    join c in bdprincipalEntities.Contas_Bancarias on bc.Bcx_codigo
                    equals c.Bcx_codigo into c_c
                    from c in c_c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Bcx_codigo = bc.Bcx_codigo,
                        Bcx_Nome = bc.Bcx_Nome,
                        Cba_Saldo_inicial = c.Cba_Saldo_inicial,
                        Bcx_tipo = bc.Bcx_tipo,
                        Cba_PDV = c.Cba_PDV,
                        Bcx_situacao = bc.Bcx_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO",
                        Emp_codigo = bc.Emp_codigo
                    }).Where(x => x.Bcx_tipo.Equals(TipoBanco)).ToList();
```

`var caixas` será desserializada posteriormente, mas devido ao `.ToList()` ela será do tipo **List** mesmo que apenas um valor seja retornado. O correto para funcionar nesse caso seria isso:

```
Where(x => x.Bcx_tipo.Equals(TipoBanco)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Dessa forma retornará apenas um valor e var caixas passará a ser do tipo **CaixasModel**.

Comment: Ótima resposta, muito obrigado, tive um problema pois a busca me retornava mais de um elemento, então tive que fazer uma pequena alteração e ficou :  " }).Where(x => x.Bcx_tipo.Equals(TipoBanco) && x.Bcx_codigo == Bcx_codigo).SingleOrDefault(); ", mas sua resposta foi ótimo, solucionou meu problema, obrigado